# Imported OpenSSH keys are saved in Gnome2 keyring, not OpenSSH

Tags: gnome, ssh, openssh, gnome2

I have run into a frustrating issue, that I am sure will be a snap to solve.

When importing an openssh key via the "Passwords & Keys" (seahorse) program, it simply places it within the "Gnome2 Key Storage" folder, which seems to cause it to not work when attempting to connect to a server.

[image]

I discussed this issue with a friend who has working keys and compared the header and footer and they appear nearly identical.

If anyone could let me know what my issue could be, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try running `ssh-add` - i might add it as answer if it works

Comment: `-i` does nothing for `ssh-add`. I assume you meant `ssh -i`? I have done that and it does work, but it's not adding it permanently. I'd like for Ubuntu to not need to ask me for my ssh key's passphrase each time I want to ssh to my server.

Comment: nope, `ssh-add` - thats it - run it on the local machine. I had to recently set up (again) the RSA keys for accessing a remote machine, and that solved it. Also, whats the output of `ssh -v USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS`? *(you can remove IP addresses and stuff if you want)*

Comment: Sorry I misread your sentence due to the lower case I. I tried that, but I still have to reuse the command each time I restart my computer. I'd rather not that to do so if possible. I'm currently away do I can't deliver on the `-v` request, but will do so when I return to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: it looks like imports in seahorse never go to the SSH storage area. (True in Ubuntu 14.04.)

Instead, **just drop the key files in `~/.ssh` and they show up by themselves in seahorse.**

Any name seemed fine here, but you need to have the corresponding `*.pub` file there as well. You can generate the `.pub` file with

```
ssh-keygen -y -f key_file > key_file.pub
```

*Note: When using `ssh` and you hit the bug with "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key." try a reboot. That worked here.*